# iOS 8/Xcode 6 - Add action to AlertSheet button

Tags: ios, image, swift, uialertsheet

I am writing a basic photo app that allows a user to push a "+" button in a navigation controller and then an ActionSheet pops up from the bottom giving the user options, here is a picture:

[image: Screenshot of my app]

I have the code to get this app working using normal buttons, but when I added it to my code for this app it crashes.  Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate
{

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func addPhoto(sender: UIBarButtonItem)
    {
        let photoOption = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Select an Input Type", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

        let photoLibraryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .Default) { (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            println("Photo Library Selected")   // Used for debugging

            // This code worked in my previous app
            let picker = UIImagePickerController()

            picker.delegate = self
            picker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

            self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .Default) { (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            println("Camera Selected")  // Used for debugging

            // This code worked in my previous app
            let picker = UIImagePickerController()

            picker.delegate = self
            picker.sourceType = .Camera

            self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

        photoOption.addAction(photoLibraryAction)
        photoOption.addAction(cameraAction)
        photoOption.addAction(cancelAction)

        self.presentViewController(photoOption, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject: AnyObject]!)
    {
        imageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

and the strange thing is after I ran this and the app crashed, I reverted back to when the code was working and the app still crashed.

Comment: What is the crash? You can't expect people to guess here or do your work for you.

Comment: @LeoNatan Obviously he _can_ expect it. It's just that he expects wrong. :)

Comment: Unfortunately I no longer have the error.  Since that app no longer worked I had to start over and I don't want to purposely crash my code again.  When I ran the app, the build was successful, the simulator opened and then immediately crashed.  It then took me to the app delegate where `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate` was highlighted in green and had some message.  I know it's not that helpful, but it might sound familiar to someone.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are running this code in the simulator. But the simulator has no camera. It's just a simulator!

Hence, trying to summon an image picker controller with a `.Camera` source type causes an exception - with a helpful error message in the console that you could have read, thus avoiding wasting bandwidth with this question...

Comment: The simulator works with the .PhotoLibrary option though, which is what I use.

Comment: It says `picker.sourceType = .Camera` right there in your code. I'm just reading what it says.